# d3 Dynamically Updating Treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update elements in the treemap:

```
    drawTreeMap = (data) ->
      margin =
        top: 0
        right: 0
        bottom: 0
        left: 0

      width = window.innerWidth
      height = window.innerHeight
      color = d3.scale.category20c()

      treemap = d3.layout.treemap().size([width, height]).sticky(true).value((d) -> d.size)

      div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .style("position", "relative")
        .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
        .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
        .style("left", margin.left + "px")
        .style("top", margin.top + "px")

      node = div.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
          .data(treemap.nodes)

      node.enter()
          .append("div")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(position)
            .style("background", (d) -> (if d.children then color(d.name) else null))
            .on "click", ->
              el = d3.select(this)
              data = el[0][0].__data__
              while (data.parent.parent)
                data = data.parent
              console.log("updated to data:")
              console.log(data)
              drawTreeMap(data)
              #updateTreemap(div, treemap, data)

      node.exit()
        .remove()

      node.transition().duration(1500).call position
```

`data` is what I want it to be in the `console.log` statement, but the treemap isn't getting updated. Most of the code is directly from the treemap example.

Comment: In your function, you're appending a new `div` and then working with that regardless of whether there already is one. You need to check thtat and update the existing one instead of appending a new one.

Comment: how exactly do I do that? don't I in fact need to add a div element for the new nodes?

Comment: No, you don't. Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582)? It shows you how to update the data and redraw.

Comment: that example doesn't add new data to the treemap, so it doesn't need to create divs.

Comment: The pattern is exactly the same for different data. You only need to handle the `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lars points out, you're creating a new div (the one assigned to var `div`) every time you call `drawTreeMap()`. For starters, you need to either simply move that div creation outside of `drawTreeMap` so that it only runs once. Or, if you want to get fancy, you could leave the creation inside the function, but do something like this:

```
div = d3.select("body").selectAll("div.treemap-container").data([null])
div.enter()
  .append('div')// only creates the div the first time this runs
  .attr('class', 'treemap-container')
  // etc...
```

That's the only odd thing I can see. Maybe there's another bug, but it's hard to track down without a working jsFiddle. If you can provide one, post a comment here and I'll take a look further.

As an aside, for style, rather than doing this: `data = el[0][0].__data__`, you should just do this: `data = el.datum()`

Finally, note that you're not using a key function for the data binding, so even if you get the treemap to re-render, there would be no object persistence (i.e. existing divs could get reassigned to a different data point arbitrarily).